# Problems with Monolog version(s) installing Data Migration Tool 2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1, monolog, data-migration

- OSX Sierra
- php 7.1.5
- apache/httpd 2.4

I have installed Magento 2 into my localhost Sites folder OK, set up the database etc. 
now trying to install data migration tool from github.

- This step (1) went OK |composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
- This step (2) "composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.1.7"
  gave me errors about monolog 1.16 & minimum stability. 
  I set m/s to "dev", still no joy, so I used
  composer to install monolog 1.16 manually - that seemed to go ok.
  Then I reran step (2) and now get this error message

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.16.0, 1.22.1].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.22.1, 1.16.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.16.0, 1.22.1].
    - magento/data-migration-tool 2.1.7 requires monolog/monolog ~1.16.0 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.16.0].
    - Installation request for magento/data-migration-tool 2.1.7 -> satisfiable by magento/data-migration-tool[2.1.7].
    - Installation request for monolog/monolog (locked at 1.22.1, required as ^1.16) -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.22.1].


Installation failed
```

What do I do to get around this issue? Maybe I already have monolog 1.22 on my Mac from working with the SLIM framework?

Help please

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1. composer remove monolog/monolog

   Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 1 removal

   - Removing monolog/monolog (1.22.1)
2. composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.1.7

   Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

   - Installing monolog/monolog (1.16.0): Loading from cache
   - Installing magento/data-migration-tool (2.1.7): Cloning 76d45af6a8 from cache

That solved the problem